# How do you scale an image's position to the size of the window in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a JavaScript function that takes an image and scales the image's distance from the center of the window when the window is scaled. So if someone scales the width of the window to 70%, the image is now 70% as far away from the center of the window. The same applies vertically, so if the window's height is scaled to 50%, the vertical distance from the image's center to the center of the window is 50%.

The function has to use the center of the image to get its position in order to scale correctly.

I tried using this code for the function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script>
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://tier-list-cache.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/movies)65.jpg
";

function continuousSpacing(image) {
    let center = {
    x: window.innerWidth / 2,
    y: window.innerHeight / 2
    };
    let distance = {
    x: image.offsetLeft - center.x,
    y: image.offsetTop - center.y
    };

    function scaleImage() {
    let currentCenter = {
        x: window.innerWidth / 2,
        y: window.innerHeight / 2
    };
    let scale = {
        x: currentCenter.x / center.x,
        y: currentCenter.y / center.y
    };
    let newDistance = {
        x: distance.x * scale.x,
        y: distance.y * scale.y
    };
    image.style.left = currentCenter.x + newDistance.x + 'px';
    image.style.top = currentCenter.y + newDistance.y + 'px';
    }

    scaleImage();

    window.addEventListener('resize', scaleImage);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently, the function instantly snaps the image to the center of the window when the window is scaled.

Comment: Maybe you could also provide HTML-Code so that we can also try it ourselves? Stackoverflow has a nice Code-Feature :D

Comment: I believe @Gykonik is talking about [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552).

Comment: Yep, thanks! Always wondered how they're called :D

Comment: If you just want to center the image, the why you are not using the css??

Comment: Please complete the HTML page in the post. It doesn't append the image to the document or specify how the image is positioned before calling `scaleImage` (which translates the image position without scaling). For a test case I suggest using an inline block element ( with a border or colored background) rather  than a link to an off-site image that may or may not be permanent. In its current state the test page "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are not updating the center and distance variables inside the scaleImage() function when the window is resized.
It needs recalculation of values based on the new dimensions of the window.

```
  function continuousSpacing(image) {
  let center = {
    x: window.innerWidth / 2,
    y: window.innerHeight / 2
  };
  let distance = {
    x: image.offsetLeft + image.offsetWidth / 2 - center.x,
    y: image.offsetTop + image.offsetHeight / 2 - center.y
  };

  function scaleImage() {
    let currentCenter = {
      x: window.innerWidth / 2,
      y: window.innerHeight / 2
    };
    let scale = {
      x: currentCenter.x / center.x,
      y: currentCenter.y / center.y
    };
    let newDistance = {
      x: distance.x * scale.x,
      y: distance.y * scale.y
    };
    image.style.left = currentCenter.x + newDistance.x - image.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
    image.style.top = currentCenter.y + newDistance.y - image.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';

    // update center and distance for next resize event
    center = currentCenter;
    distance = {
      x: image.offsetLeft + image.offsetWidth / 2 - center.x,
      y: image.offsetTop + image.offsetHeight / 2 - center.y
    };
  }

  scaleImage();

  window.addEventListener('resize', scaleImage);
}
```

the **center** and **distance** variables are updated inside the scaleImage() function after the image is repositioned. This will ensures that the next time the scaleImage() function is called (on the next resize event), it will  update center and distance values to calculate the new image position.

Comment: This is still snapping the image to the center of the screen instantly.

Comment: I have added few changes, if that works.